# Undefined control sequence, extra \fi and overfull \hbox errors

Tags: errors, symbols, undefined

I am using the code below to add the list of symbols to my document. I am getting the following  errors for the rows where the function `\ifthenelse` is used:

1. Undefined control sequence for all of them
2. Extra \fi only for the first 2 (so for the \addchap{List of Symbols part and the one with symbol)
3. Overfull \hbox for the one with the symbol

```
% Symbolverzeichnis
\ifthenelse{\boolean{english}}{\addchap{List of Symbols}}{\addchap{Symbolverzeichnis}}
\begin{center}
\hspace{-17mm}\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedleft}p{0.08\linewidth} p{0.3\linewidth} >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{0.2\linewidth}}
\ifthenelse{\boolean{english}}{symbol}{Symbol} 
&
\ifthenelse{\boolean{english}}{name}{Bezeichnung} & \ifthenelse{\boolean{english}}{unit}{Einheit} \\\hline
$a$ & \ifthenelse{\boolean{english}}{acceleration}{Beschleunigung} & $\unit{\frac{m}{s^2}}$\\
$F$ & \ifthenelse{\boolean{english}}{force}{Kraft} & $\unit{N}$
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Please provide a complete example, see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228.

Comment: you have not shown the error, or even said which command was undefined and you have not provided any example that allows anyone to reproduce the error.

Comment: Overfull `\hbox` just refers a line that LaTeX had some trouble setting to its liking. Unless the line visually looks bad, there's usually no need to make any changes.